Maximal principle for distributional subsolution of laplcace operator on Riemannian manifold
Let $U$ be a coordinate neighborhood of a Riemannian manifold $M$ and $f$ is a bounded positive function(not necessarily continuous). Suppose $\Delta f\geq0$ in the sense of distribution i.e.:
for all compactly supported smooth test function $\eta$, we have
$$
\int f\Delta \eta \geq 0
$$
Can we find an upper semi-continuous representation $F$ of $f$, such that F satisfies weak maximum principle in the region $U$?(since f is define a.e., we can hardly talk about its value at certain boundaries, it is necessasry to replace it with a true function).
I already know that for Euclidean space, this is true, but in general, I guess it is true however I don't know how to prove.
